Обьясните что происходит после return, и как это записать проще и понятнее?
Смысл функции игнорировать регистры в списке.
def is_contains(string: str, list_: list):
    count_calls()
    return True if string.lower() in [word.lower() for word in list_] else False


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Что происходит после return:
return True if string.lower() in [word.lower() for word in list_]:
Здесь берется строка string и переводится в нижний регистр в string.lower(). Далее оператор in сравнивает эту string в нижнем регистре с каждой строкой в списке list_.
[word.lower() for word in list_] разворачивается в цикл for word in list_, который перебирает каждый элемент списка и переводит его в нижний регистр: word.lower().
Если совпадений нет, то возвращается False.

Как проще записать - убрать тернарный оператор, он тут не нужен: return string.lower() in [word.lower() for word in list_]

Можно ещё короче написать return string.lower() in set(map(str.lower, list_))

lower -> casefold. str.casefold.

@CrazyElf, set не нужен, всё будет работать и с генератором: return string.casefold() in map(str.casefold, list_).

"Как это записать проще и понятнее" — такие вопросы задают на Code Review при условии, что код рабочий. Сообщество англоязычное, но вопросы такого рода должны задаваться там. А по поводу того, что тут происходит, вам в комментах объяснили. Но ваш вопрос конечно...

Вот что это значит:
def is_contains(string: str, list_: list):
    count_calls()
    lst = [] # Генератор
    for word in list_:
        lst.append(word.lower())

    if string.lower() in lst: # Тернарный оператор
        return True
    else:
        return False


А что происходит внутри квадратных скобок?

внутри квадратных скобок в этом коде ничего не происходит. Это просто список. У вас в коде это генератор, грубо говоря, немного другой объект, но со схожим функционалом (в рамках этой задачи). Могу посоветовать почитать про генераторы, это довольно обширная тема для одного вопроса @Sstaf

Тот же функционал можно переписать следующим образом:
def is_contains(string: str, list_: list):
    count_calls()
    string = string.lower()
    for word in list_:
        if word.lower() == string:
            return True

    return False


Имеет смысл привести искомую строку в нижний регистр один раз

Чтобы не создавать список и не тратить память понапрасну, берем генератор и потребляем его в функции any. Что in, что ==, все равно. Как только any встретит успешное равенство, перебор списка слов прекращается и возвращается True. Иначе вернет False.
def is_contains(string: str, list_: list):
    count_calls()
    return any(string.lower() == word.lower() for word in list_)

